# What's the difference between using a function with "()" and when we use it without them in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, backend

```
function find() {
    console.log("Request handler 'find' was called.");
}
function display() {
    console.log("Request handler 'display' was called.");
}
```

exports.find      = find;
exports.display = display;

1. sometime we call function with parentheses and sometimes we don't use them.

Like in DOM i get why we do no t use it with event Listeners because we want to them to only work when click occurs, But in node like the above example why we didn't used any parentheses?

Comment: When you don't use parenthesis, you **don't call** the function.

Comment: Functions are *first class citizens* in JavaScript.  This means you can assign them to variables, pass them as arguments, and return them from other functions.

Comment: No difference between nodejs exports and dom event handlers really: you don't call the function so that someone else can call the function at a time/place when it's desirable for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without the parentheses you are assigning the function itself ( functions are first class objects ) whereas with the parentheses you are executing the function and assigning the resultant value